# Spree ProductFilters do not work anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I got a problem defining new dynamic ProductFilters for Spree 2.0.4

My customer has got Categories (e.g. Taxons). A Product belongs to one category and has maximum 8 Properties BUT the Properties also depend on the Category each Product is in AND the Position of the Property is also important.

My Solution was to extend the Database in an unnormalized way:

```
module Spree
  Taxon.class_eval do


    belongs_to :prop1,  class_name: "Spree::Property",
                        foreign_key: "p1_id"
    belongs_to :prop2,  class_name: "Spree::Property",
                        foreign_key: "p2_id"
    belongs_to :prop3,  class_name: "Spree::Property",
                        foreign_key: "p3_id"
    belongs_to :prop4,  class_name: "Spree::Property",
                        foreign_key: "p4_id"
    belongs_to :prop5,  class_name: "Spree::Property",
                        foreign_key: "p5_id"
    belongs_to :prop6,  class_name: "Spree::Property",
                        foreign_key: "p6_id"
    belongs_to :prop7,  class_name: "Spree::Property",
                        foreign_key: "p7_id"
    belongs_to :prop8,  class_name: "Spree::Property",
                        foreign_key: "p8_id"

    attr_accessible :prop1, :prop2, :prop3, :prop4, :prop5, :prop6, :prop7, :prop8


    def properties
      prop = []
      prop << prop1
      prop << prop2
      prop << prop3
      prop << prop4
      prop << prop5
      prop << prop6
      prop << prop7
      prop << prop8
      return prop
    end

    def applicable_filters
      fs = []
      fs << Spree::Core::ProductFilters.price_filter if Spree::Core::ProductFilters.respond_to?(:price_filter)
      #fs << Spree::Core::ProductFilters.brand_filter if Spree::Core::ProductFilters.respond_to?(:brand_filter)          
      fs
    end


  end
end
```

So that I'm able to get the possible properties in a taxon for the corresponding product. I now made 8 Filters for each taxon property (prop1 .. prop8) because some values are numerical and should be handled different from text values, so even that's not completely DRY I came to the following solution:

```
module Spree
  module Core
    module ProductFilters

      if Spree::Property.table_exists?
        Spree::Product.add_search_scope :selective_prop1_any do |*opts|
          conds = opts.map {|o| ProductFilters.selective_prop1_filter[:conds][o]}.reject {|c| c.nil?}
          scope = conds.shift
          conds.each do |new_scope|
            scope = scope.or(new_scope)
          end
          Spree::Product.where(scope)
        end

        def ProductFilters.selective_prop1_filter(taxon = nil, locale = 'en')
          return if taxon.nil? #||= Spree::Taxon.find_by_permalink!("categories")
          property = taxon.prop1
          scope = Spree::ProductProperty.where(:property_id => property, :locale => locale).
                                         joins(:product => :taxons).
                                         where("#{Spree::Taxon.table_name}.id" => [taxon] + taxon.descendants).
                                         scoped
          brands = scope.pluck(:value).uniq
          {
            :name   => property.presentation,
            :scope  => :selective_prop1_any,
            :labels => brands.sort.map { |k| [k,k] }
          }
        end
      end

      if Spree::Property.table_exists?
        Spree::Product.add_search_scope :selective_prop2_any do |*opts|
          conds = opts.map {|o| ProductFilters.selective_prop2_filter[:conds][o]}.reject {|c| c.nil?}
          Rails.logger.debug conds.inspect
          scope = conds.shift
          Rails.logger.debug scope.inspect
          conds.each do |new_scope|
            scope = scope.or(new_scope)
          end
          Rails.logger.debug scope.inspect
          Spree::Product.where(scope)
        end

# ... other filters cut out for brevity

      if Spree::Property.table_exists?
        Spree::Product.add_search_scope :selective_prop8_any do |*opts|
          [..]
        end

        def ProductFilters.selective_prop8_filter(taxon = nil, locale = 'en')
          [..]
        end
      end

      Spree::Product.add_search_scope :price_range_any do |*opts|
        conds = opts.map {|o| Spree::Core::ProductFilters.price_filter[:conds][o]}.reject {|c| c.nil?}
        scope = conds.shift
        conds.each do |new_scope|
          scope = scope.or(new_scope)
        end
        Spree::Product.joins(:master => :default_price).where(scope)
      end

      def ProductFilters.format_price(amount)
        Spree::Money.new(amount)
      end

      def ProductFilters.price_filter
        v = Spree::Price.arel_table
        conds = [ [ Spree.t(:under_price, :price => format_price(10))   , v[:amount].lteq(10)],
                  [ "#{format_price(10)} - #{format_price(15)}"        , v[:amount].in(10..15)],
                  [ "#{format_price(15)} - #{format_price(18)}"        , v[:amount].in(15..18)],
                  [ "#{format_price(18)} - #{format_price(20)}"        , v[:amount].in(18..20)],
                  [ Spree.t(:or_over_price, :price => format_price(20)) , v[:amount].gteq(20)]]
        { :name   => Spree.t(:price_range),
          :scope  => :price_range_any,
          :conds  => Hash[*conds.flatten],
          :labels => conds.map {|k,v| [k,k]}
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Due to the fact, that even the values of the Properties should be localized, a made a column locale in the ProductProperties table. My selective filters pass the locale Variable to retrieve the correct ProductProperty.

Because of the MVC restrictions not being able to pass the locale from session[:locale] and the current taxon to the model I overwrote the original display logic which is using the applicable_filters method for the taxon in the CONTROLLER(!) like so:

```
TaxonsController.class_eval do
    def show
      @taxon = Taxon.find_by_permalink(params[:id])

      return unless @taxon

      if @taxon
        @filters = []
        @filters << Spree::Core::ProductFilters.selective_prop1_filter(@taxon, locale) unless @taxon.prop1.nil?
        [...]
        @filters << Spree::Core::ProductFilters.selective_prop8_filter(@taxon, locale) unless @taxon.prop8.nil?
        @filters.concat(@taxon.applicable_filters)
      else
        @filters = Spree::Core::ProductFilters.all_taxons
      end
      p = params.merge(:taxon => @taxon.id)
      @searcher = Spree::Config.searcher_class.new(params)
      @searcher.current_user = try_spree_current_user
      @searcher.current_currency = current_currency

      @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
    end
  end
```

And here's the mainly left original view code:

```
<% unless @filters.empty? %>
  <%= form_tag '', :method => :get, :id => 'sidebar_products_search' do %>
    <% params[:search] ||= {} %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'per_page', params[:per_page] %>
    <% @filters.each do |filter| %>
      <% labels = filter[:labels] || filter[:conds].map {|m,c| [m,m]} %>
      <% next if labels.empty? %>
      <div class="" data-hook="navigation">
        <h5 class="filter-title"> <%= filter[:name] %> </h5>
          <% labels.each do |nm,val| %>
            <% label = "#{filter[:name]}_#{nm}".gsub(/\s+/,'_') %>
            <label for="<%= label %>" class="checkbox" style="display:block;"><%= nm %><input type="checkbox"
                   id="<%= label %>"
                   name="search[<%= filter[:scope].to_s %>][]"
                   value="<%= val %>"
                   <%= params[:search][filter[:scope]] && params[:search][filter[:scope]].include?(val.to_s) ? "checked" : "" %> />
            </label>
          <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag Spree.t(:search), :name => nil, :class => 'button' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The display works like it should: Depending on the taxon the user is in, the values from ProductProperties in the session[:locale] are fetched and displayed correctly, but now there comes the Problem:

The Search doesn't work work anymore. Even the not modified :price_range_any filter does not work. All Products belonging to the current taxon are always displayed. The search hash in params hash is built correct by the form `search => {"price_range_any":["10.00 € EUR - 15.00 € EUR"]}`

I've no idea. If I switch back to the original files by removing the overwrites everything is working.

How can I get my filters to run correctly?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. But after I restart rails server the problem goes away. Maybe try that?